# S.M.A.R.T. Statistics

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart

How are S.M.A.R.T. statistics different from S.M.A.R.T. attributes?

For example, I have two drives. The first has 8 `current pending sector count`s and 8 `offline uncorrectable` sectors. These are both attributes; this drive doesn't support statistics. The smart daemon warned my about these problems, and since I'm familiar with how serious they are I replaced the drive pronto.

The second drive has 6 `number of mechanical start failures`: a statistic. It sounds serious, but the smart daemon did not warn me about them and so I don't know when they occurred. The drive is a year old, but all six events could have happened in the first six weeks for all I know. The drive's attributes are all OK.

Comment: Can't say I've ever seen a distinction between stats and attrib. To me the attribute is the name of the collection item, and the value is the statistic.

Comment: They're on different tabs in the gsmartcontrol UI. Attributes have: failed, norm'd, worst, threshold, raw, type, flags. Statistics have: value, flags, page, offset.

Comment: The smartd manual mentions [ACS-2 (ATA/ATAPI Command Set - 2)](http://www.t13.org/documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2011/d2015r7-ATAATAPI_Command_Set_-_2_ACS-2.pdf) which is linked from the [Wikipedia S.M.A.R.T. article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.). Relevant section Annex A.5. It is simply a description of the individual statistics plus binary layout. There is no motivating purpose. Many of the fields already exist as S.M.A.R.T. attributes, so there is quite a bit of overlap. You'd likely have to be familiar with the politics of S.M.A.R.T. to explain the difference between the two.